# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I am installing android studio .its throwing these errors

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK

package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

i have good internet connection
[image: This is the error]

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK

package Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System

Image: Tag mismatch!.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK

package Sources for Android 34: Tag mismatch!.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK

package Android SDK Platform 34: Tag mismatch!.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK

package Android SDK Build-Tools 34: Tag mismatch!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reinstalling of Android Studio, Jet Brains after clean deletion then issue is solved